# Problem with default checked checkboxes: Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

I have created the following function to check the first value of the check box when loading a page -

```
function defaultCheck(){
      document.checkBoxForm.list[0].checked = true;
      var val=document.checkBoxForm.list[0].value;
      showtotal[0] = document.checkBoxForm.list[0].value;
      show(val);
      editVal();
      //alert('ajhsdjha');
 }
```

I have used the function in html page load by `<body onload="defaultCheck()">`.

My problem is - when there are more than one values in the list the function by default selects the first one but when there is just one value in the list, it does not select it. The values of check boxes are dynamically retrieved from database by -

```
 <?php
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($levelq)) {?>
        <input type='checkbox' name="list" value="<?=$row['tag']?>"  
               id="<?=$row['tag']?>" onclick="" />
        <?  echo $row['tag'].' '.'<br/><br/>'; 
     }
?>
```

I have no idea why is it behaving so weird. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @cwallenpoole said, you should be doing this in PHP.

If you still want to do it in JS, here you go:

```
function defaultCheck(){
      if(document.checkBoxForm.list.length > 1) {
          document.checkBoxForm.list[0].checked = true;
          var val=document.checkBoxForm.list[0].value;
          showtotal[0] = document.checkBoxForm.list[0].value;
      } else {
          document.checkBoxForm.list.checked=true;
          var val=document.checkBoxForm.list.value;
           showtotal[0] = document.checkBoxForm.list.value;
      }
      show(val);
      editVal();
      //alert('ajhsdjha');
 }
```

This happens because, when there is only 1 checkbox, list refers to that checkbox, NOT the array of checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet money that the problem is the use of `[0]`. Have you considered removing that?

But, that said, you shouldn't be doing this in JS anyway, you should do this in PHP:

```
 $checked = 'checked="true"';
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($levelq)) {
    // you also may wish to consider using list[] instead of list. That will make
    // reading the value much easier in PHP
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name="list" value="<?=$row['tag']?>"  
           id="<?=$row['tag']?>" onclick="" <?=$checked?> />
    <?  echo $row['tag'].' '.'<br/><br/>'; 
    $checked = "";
 }
```

Comment: Won't it check all the values instead of just checking the first one?

Comment: @Pow No. If you look before the loop, there is `$checked = '';`, it is then output with `<?=$checked?>` inside the loop. Right before this iteration ends, it is set `$checked = "";`> That will make all of the other iterations print nothing instead of checked="true"